# Access image/sprite from project folder instead of Hierarchy (scene)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change an image of a SpriteRenderer component attached to a GameObject with an image which is in another GameObject in the scene. It's easy, simple access the SpriteRenderer component of the other object and replace images.

```js
tile.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = GameObjectA.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
```

BUT since I am doing it with multiple images I was wondering if there was a way I could access this image from the Project Folder, i.e. "Unity Project" instead of creating independent GameObjects and therefore attaching SpriteRenderer and hence referring to independent sprites/images.

```js
tile.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you want to do, is to have some way to reference an asset from a MonoBehaviour. There's a really easy way to do that in Unity: create a public field (field, not a property) of that type (`Sprite` in this case), and then, click on the gameObject with this MonoBehaviour, and you'll see the field. You can do this either with a single entity, array or list, and the code looks just like this:

```
public SomeBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

    public Sprite SomeSprite;
    public Sprite[] SomeSpriteArray;

}
```

You then would be able to assign an asset to it, either by dragging it to the field, or by opening a dialog with a circle button to the right.

Comment: @Daqs glad to help. If you found an answer to be correct and helpful, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: sorry for the delay. I just did.